# How to validate on python to check for no user input

Tags: python, validation

Hi i wrote some code for a maths program and wanted some help to validate user input. I want the program to, when the user ignores a question and simply presses the enter key for the next question, to show them the exact same question again and notify them saying every question must be attempted. Heres the code i have so far

```
import time
import random
msg=0
questionsAsked=0
score=0
op = ["-","*","+"]
username= input("What is your name? ")
print("Okay "+username+ " lets begin the test. Good luck!")
praise= ["Well done!","Great job!", "Spot on!", "Perfect!"]
wrong = ["Unlucky!", "Not quite", "Incorrect"]
def actual(num1,num2,operation):
    actual=eval(str(num1) + operation + (str(num2)))
    return actual

def useranswer(num1,num2,operation):
    useranswer=int(input(str(num1)+operation+str(num2)+"= "))
    return useranswer

while questionsAsked <10:
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(0,12)
    operation = random.choice(op)
    praiseMsg= random.choice(praise)
    wrongMsg= random.choice(wrong)

    if useranswer(num1,num2,operation) != actual(num1,num2,operation):
        print(wrongMsg)                       
    else:
        print(praiseMsg)
        score= score+1
    questionsAsked=questionsAsked+1


else:
    if score>5:
        msg= str("Well done "+username+"! You scored over 50%")
    else:
        msg=str("Better luck next time " + username)
    print("You scored " +str(score)+ " out of 10. \n" +msg )
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
username = raw_input("What is your name? ")
while not username:
    username = raw_input("Not understood.  What is your name?")
```

You could wrap this in a function:

```
def insist_upon_answer(prompt):
    answer = raw_input(prompt)
    while not answer:
        answer = raw_input("All questions must be answered. {}".format(prompt)
    return answer
```

and call it:

```
name = insist_upon_answer("What is your name?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like triphook's answer, for Python 3:

```
username = input("Input: ")
while username=="":
    username = input("Input (again): ")
```